# How can I stop my average output from displaying the same letter grade as my original grade output? Also how to make sentinel values case insensitve?

Tags: c#

I have a program that is supposed to return your grades and grade average to you using a sentinel value to end the program, while also using input validation. The issue that I am having at the moment is that it runs greatly and it stops when I use "Quit", but my ending prompt of:

```
Console.WriteLine("The average is {0} is a(n) {1}", average, grade);
```

is returning me the same letter grade as the prompt for my:

```
Console.WriteLine("A grade of {0} is a(n) {1}", anInt, grade);
```

I also need to make the quit be case insensitive so I tried to use the `.ToLower()` method, my program would not run properly and I would get an error that says "error CS0019: Operator `==' cannot be applied to operands of type` method group' and `string'".

My code is listed below and I was wondering if the issue is that I am using the same string function to return both letters and that is why they are mimicking one another? For example, if I enter a grade that is returned as an F as the last letter in the program, the average grade will show as an F at the end of the program regardless of what the numerical grade value that represents the average is. I was also wondering if there was a proper way to implement the `.ToLower()` method, because I have tried it a few times and it kept giving me errors, so I just removed it as a whole.

```
using System;
class Program {
  public static void Main (string[] args) {
    int sum=0;
    int count = 0;
    string grade = "A";
    bool KeepGoing = true;
      
    while (KeepGoing){
      string entry = GetEntry();
      if (entry == "Quit") {
        KeepGoing = false;
      } else {
      int anInt = Convert.ToInt32(entry);
      
      grade = DetermineGrade(anInt);
      sum += anInt;
      count++;

      Console.WriteLine("A grade of {0} is a(n) {1}", anInt, grade);
     }
    
    }
    double average = sum/ (double)count;
    Console.WriteLine("The average is {0} is a(n) {1}", average, grade);
    
  }
  
  public static string DetermineGrade(int anInt) {
      if (anInt >= 90){
      return "A";            
    }
      if (anInt >= 80 & anInt <= 89){
      return "B";    
    }
      if (anInt >= 70 & anInt <= 79){
      return "C";
    }
      if (anInt >= 60 & anInt <= 69){
      return "D";
    }
      else{
      return "F"; 
    }
  }
 
  public static string GetEntry() {
    while (true){
     Console.WriteLine("Please enter your grade or enter Quit to end program.");
     string entry = Console.ReadLine();
     if (entry == "Quit"){
       return entry;
     }
     int anInt;
      if (Int32.TryParse (entry, out anInt)) {
        if (anInt>= 0 && anInt <= 100) {
          return entry;
        } else {
          Console.WriteLine("Error: Please enter a valid integer!");
      }
     }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Step through your code in a debugger. Look at what each line is doing, what values are going into methods when you call them, and what values are coming out of the methods.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*"How can I stop my average output from displaying the same letter grade as my original grade output?"*

You must call `DetermineGrade` again with the average. The variable `grade` will not change by itself.

The problem is that `average` is a `double` but `DetermineGrade` wants an `int` input. You could simply change the type of the input parameter to `double`. `int` arguments will automatically be converted to `double`.

The method can be simplified. Since the first case returns when the input is >= 90, you don't need to test whether it is <= 89 in the second case. The same is true for the following cases.

```cs
public static string DetermineGrade(double value) {
    if (value >= 90.0) return "A";
    if (value >= 80.0) return "B";
    if (value >= 70.0) return "C";
    if (value >= 60.0) return "D";
    return "F";
}
```

And then

```cs
string averageGrade = DetermineGrade(average);
Console.WriteLine("The average is {0} is a(n) {1}", average, averageGrade );
```

You can also use a [switch expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/switch-expression) (since C# 8.0) and [relational patterns](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/functional/pattern-matching#relational-patterns) (since C# 9.0) and a [expression bodied method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/statements-expressions-operators/expression-bodied-members#methods) (since C# 6.0):

```cs
public static string DetermineGrade(double value) =>
    value switch {
         >= 90.0 => "A",
         >= 80.0 => "B",
         >= 70.0 => "C",
         >= 60.0 => "D",
         _ => "F"
    };
```

---

*"Also how to make sentinel values case insensitve?"*

Using `.ToLower()` is an option. Another possibility is to use

```cs
while (true) { // Infinite loop.
    string entry = GetEntry();
    if (String.Equals(entry, "Quit", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)) {
        break; // Exit the while loop.
    }
    ...
}
```

You also have the option to use `CurrentCultureIgnoreCase` or `InvariantCultureIgnoreCase` instead. This can make a difference for the Turkish culture, because they have two different "i"s (+ one without the dot) that may be handled differently.

In simple situations, where no accents or other special or foreign characters are used, `OrdinalIgnoreCase` will do it.

Comment: Thank you so much! I really appreciate your help!